# How would I create a radial gradient in my border?

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

[image: box with radial gradient]

Basically, this is just a block element:

```
<div></div>

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**How would I put the radial gradient image inside the top left of the elements border?**

Comment: I'm feeling a positioned pseudo element coming on. :) How wide is this border anyway?

Comment: Depends. Can be 1px up to 100px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `border-image` with some `radial-gradient` like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div><div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:blue;
  border-style:solid;
  border-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(-15% -15%, farthest-side, red, blue) 20/8;
  border-image:-moz-radial-gradient(-15% -15%, farthest-side, red, blue) 20/8; //Will work starting with FF29.
  border-image:radial-gradient(-15% -15%, farthest-side, red, blue) 20/8;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZSLH/10/)

**NOTE**: Unfortunately Internet Explorer does not support this yet. The current version of Firefox (29.0.1) does [have support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709587), but all previous versions including ESRs won't render it correctly, and there is nothing on the horizon for IE, and all past versions will never support this method. If you need to support any versions of IE, you'll need to use another method, such as using a pseudo-element `:before`.

Comment: Can't get it to work in Firefox, either with `radial-gradient` or -moz-radial-gradient`.

Comment: Additionally this doesn't work in any versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I've not tested on FF and IE, however I'm sure that those browser have not supported this feature yet, they interpret the CSS in another way, looking for the `url` which is the must-present word in the value for the `border-image`, while we all know that `radial-gradient` and `linear-gradient` are able to use as image (for `background-image`). This lack of support is too annoying, Chrome and Opera are so modern compared to those. I'll add note about this and hope that in future those browsers will catch up with the modernity.

Comment: Interestingly, even the young browser like `Maxthon` also renders it OK, I'm pretty sorry for the FF and IE :(

Comment: True, though I'd hardly call Firefox less modern than Chrome. Both `radial-gradient` and `border-image` are supported ... just not together. It's a very specific use-case. I think a ticket needs to be opened in Bugzilla to add support.

Comment: I love this solution. It doesn't need to introduce a new DOM element. Could you explain the `radial-gradient(-15% -15%, farthest-side, red, blue) 20/8;` part a bit more? What do the parameters mean?

Comment: @Kriem the first space-separated argument is for position of the center point (we know that radial gradient has a center point), the second argument is to say the end of the radial should be the farthest-side (you can also use `farthest-corner` in this case), the next arguments are for declaring `color-stop`, the first is positioned at `0%` and the last is positioned at `100%`, you can insert more color stops (comma separated), all the middle color stops should have position like this `yellow 30%`, `green 50%`, ... Finally, you can search more for the `radial-gradient`, it has a lot to read...

Comment: Opened a ticket with Mozilla, and found out it was a duplicate. This is fully supported as of FF29, which is in beta, and will be released on April 15. You'll still need to use '-moz-radial-gradient` as well though, and you'll probably want to use `radial-gradient` to future-proof the code. Additionally though, this code is incorrect, and only working because of a bug in Chrome. You need to specify `border-style:solid`, or it'll stop working when Chrome fixes the bug.

Comment: @Kriem the `20` is the value for `border-image-slice`, `8` is for `border-image-width`, the `/` is required (just a syntax). You should also search for the `border-image` to read more, it's fairly complicated, the syntax I used is not the full syntax although it's enough.

Comment: @AndyM thanks for the info, this should be supported in all browsers, I'm pretty happy that looks like new browsers support the newest features of CSS3 very well (like Maxthon did).

Comment: Glad to help, and great answer. Fix the missing `border-style` and you'll get my +1.

Comment: @AndyM what do you mean? why is the `border-style` missing? Doesn't the result look like what the OP wants?

Comment: It only looks that way due to a bug in Webkit, which will be fixed eventually. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99922, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356802. When Webkit implemented it's experimental version, it set `border-image` to override `border-style`, and the official spec says not to. There are tickets both in Webkit and Chrome to fix this, so in the future, this code won't work.

Comment: @AndyM well updated, I've read a book saying just the behavior (the border-image will render the border regardless of the border-style effect) but it did not say that's a bug.

Comment: Part of the problem is that people use write books about CSS that isn't finalized yet, and treat experimental browser-specific implementations as production-ready code. Using new features is great, but we've got to be careful to watch for changes made to the official spec. Thanks for adding that code, +1.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ypJ8k/2/

```
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

You can do it without pseudo elements like after so your gradiant will be much more accurate

the big wall of css is just the gradiant. go to http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, paste that gradiant (you have space before and after so you can copy it nicely from the fiddle) and modifie it at will

updated: bigger size (300x300). http://jsfiddle.net/ypJ8k/3/

Comment: Although this needs the introduction of an extra DOM element.

Comment: Indeed, but probably much better support in old browsers. sadly many companies still want their webs available (as best as possible) in ie7.

Answer (score 1):

One pseudo element should be enough with a radial gradient background from the corner and appropriate color stop.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ukxCH/)

**CSS**

```
.element {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:50px auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.element:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width:120%;
  height:120%;
  top:-20%;
  left:-20%;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left,red ,lightblue 50%, lightblue);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top left,red ,lightblue 50%, lightblue);
  background: radial-gradient(top left,red ,lightblue 50%, lightblue);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: @AndyM Thanks for adding the extra vendor prefixes